# Sales Order & Invoice Product Data Start from Below Shipping address

Tags: php, vtiger

This is an Sales Order and Export to PDF by Vtiger CRM 5.4.0, unfortunately the shipping address are too long, and overlap the product data.  Vtiger are using Coding to generate to PDF.

have any idea to let product data start from little bit bottom ?
changing which coding in which php page?

i have attached a picture according my product data are overlap by shipping address 
[image]

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: vtiger is an open source file, and the total of file are around 70MB, i have no idea where is the file to edit the creating PDF format.

Comment: If setting some breaks before products table is OK let me know.

Comment: @HPM yes , that is OK too. any solution?

Comment: I have done any thing on vtiger pdf outputs. I'll soon check my scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **First version**

Products table list is created in `\vtigercrm\vtlib\Vtiger\PDF\inventory\ContentViewer.php` `Line:35`

```
function initDisplay($parent) {

    $pdf = $parent->getPDF();
    $contentFrame = $parent->getContentFrame();

################
# My added line

$contentFrame->y += 32;
$contentFrame->h -= 32;

# End added line
################

    $pdf->MultiCell($contentFrame->w, $contentFrame->h, "", 1, 'L', 0, 1, $contentFrame->x, $contentFrame->y);
```

`$contentFrame` Holds products table list specification. After adding y position of content frame, we should decrease height of frame, in order to avoid sending all the frame to next page.

If you only want to change sales order PDF and not other PDFs (Quote, Invoice, ...) You should override some of vtiger inventory pdf class in `\vtigercrm\modules\SalesOrder\SalesOrderPDFController.php`.